# Changing a color when hovering

Tags: html, css

I am working on my exam with html/css, and I have a question - we're supposed to make a website for fonts, and I want to have a index page where I want to have one of the fonts showcased like this

R/r 
Roboto

And the font is colored in white, while the seperator is colored in a blue color, however I want the seperator to turn to white, while the rest of the text turns to blue.

For now I have this:

```css
a:hover {
  color: #00ebff;
  transition:
}
```

```html
<a href="roboto.html">
  <h1>R<span style="color: #00ebff" class="spacer">/</span>r</h1>
  <h2>Roboto</h2>
</a>
```

And I cant for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Comment: You want `spacer` to be while colored while hovering `a`?

Comment: just a small note - in the past it was considered bad to nest a block level element (such as a H1) inside an inline level element (such as an "a"). Now - with the advent of HTML5 - it is considered valid, but  perhaps should not be done for code quality purposes - you should have <h1><a>...</a></h1>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're along the right line, but you need to be more specific in the selector for the separator element. The following CSS should achieve what you need:

```
a:hover {
    color: #00ebff;
}

a:hover span.spacer {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Please note that using the `!important` rule here is essential, since you're using inline styles. However, it would be much better to define the style for `.spacer` in your CSS file too:

```css
a .spacer {
  color: #00ebff
}

a:hover {
  color: #00ebff;
}

a:hover .spacer {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="roboto.html">
     <h1>R<span class="spacer">/</span>r</h1>
         <h2>Roboto</h2>
 </a>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.spacer{
  color: #00ebff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #00ebff;
}

a:hover h1 .spacer{
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: Or if you **must** use the inline styles: `a:hover h1 .spacer{ color: white !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:hover {
  color: #00ebff !important;
}
a:hover span.spacer {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="roboto.html">
  <h1>R<span style="color: #00ebff" class="spacer">/</span>r</h1>
  <h2>Roboto</h2>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
    .spacer{
      color: #fff;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #00ebff;
    }

    a:hover .spacer{
       color: white !important;
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. The `.spacer` element will always be `#00ebff`.

Comment: you asked the space color to turn white this should work

Comment: No, inline styles always take precedence unless you use `!important`. Please see my answer.

Comment: yes i agree with you but the question is to to turn spacer to white then we have to use important.

Comment: Exactly, which you haven't done in your code above. Therefore the answer you've posted won't achieve what the OP is asking for (i.e. turning `.spacer` white on `hover`).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.